# PHP function to calculate geometric standard deviation

Tags: php, arrays

I wrote a function to calculate geometric mean and geometric standard deviation of a set of values. I got the GM correct. But the GSD is wrong. Where did I make a mistake?

```
<?php
function geometric_mean($a) {
 foreach($a as $i=>$n) {$mul = $i == 0 ? $n : $mul*$n;}
  $gm= pow($mul,1/count($a));

 foreach($a as $i=>$n) {$gsd = $i == 0 ? $n : $gsd+=pow(log($i/$gm),2);}

 $temp=exp(sqrt($gsd/count($a)));
 return array($gm,$temp);

}

$values=array(12.05,18,24,56,8.9,5.4);

$g=geometric_mean($values);
print_r($g);
?>
```

The GSD in this case is 2.11, but I am getting something else

Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_standard_deviation for formula

Comment: Just a quick observation to get rid of the confusing `$mul = $i == 0 ?` construction: if you initialize `$mul = 1` before the loop you can just write `foreach($a as $n) $mul *= $n`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the line `$gsd = $i == 0 ? $n : $gsd+=pow(log($i/$gm),2);`  be something like `$gsd = $i == 0 ? pow(log($n/$gm),2) : $gsd + pow(log($i/$gm),2);` (again, you can rewrite this without the ternary operator).